# A PowerShell script to list all files and folders within a directory

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I've been trying to find a script that recursively prints all files and folders within a directory like this where the backslash is used to indicate directories:

```
Source code\
Source code\Base\
Source code\Base\main.c
Source code\Base\print.c
List.txt
```

I'm using PowerShell 3.0 and most other scripts I've found do not work (though they didn't anything like what I'm asking).

Additionally: I need it to be recursive.

Answer (score 18):

It seems that you are looking for a way to distinguish files from directories. Luckily there is a property called `PSIsContainer` that is true for directories and false for files.

```
dir -r  | % { if ($_.PsIsContainer) { $_.FullName + "\" } else { $_.FullName } }

C:\Source code\Base\
C:\Source code\List.txt
C:\Source code\Base\main.c
C:\Source code\Base\print.c
```

If the leading path information is not desirable, you can remove it easily enough using `-replace`:

```
dir | % { $_.FullName -replace "C:\\","" }
```

Comment: @Guvante the `\ ` must be escaped in a regex!! The first parameter for `-replace` is a regex!!

Comment: The exclamation points make it more righter. http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/the-1-phenomenon

Comment: @EBGreen unfortunately I can not edit my comment to add some 'one' after  my exclamation points ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, this script is not recursive. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Can you edit it so that it doesn't print out the name of the folder that the process is taking place in (`List.txt` is NOT in `Source code`) and so that the order is like in Windows Explorer where the folders come first.

Answer (score 5):

It could be like:

```
$path = "c:\Source code"
DIR $path -Recurse | % { 
    $_.fullname -replace [regex]::escape($path), (split-path $path -leaf)
}
```

Following the @Goyuix idea:

```
$path = "c:\source code"
DIR $path -Recurse | % {
    $d = "\"
    $o = $_.fullname -replace [regex]::escape($path), (split-path $path -leaf)
    if ( -not $_.psiscontainer) {
        $d = [string]::Empty 
    }
    "$o$d"
}
```

Comment: @Melab Add parameter to your script to pass-in the path, in all the answers here the path is hard-code for convenience... read about how create a powershell script with paramenters...

Comment: How do I do that? I doubt it will order them in the right way. See my comment on Goyux's answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
dir | % {
   $p= (split-path -noqualifier $_.fullname).substring(1)
   if($_.psiscontainer) {$p+'\'} else {$p}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This one shows full paths, as some of the other answers do, but is shorter:

```
ls -r | % { $_.FullName + $(if($_.PsIsContainer){'\'}) }
```

However, the OP I believe asked for *relative paths* (i.e. relative to the current directory) and only @C.B.'s answer addressed that point. So by just adding a `substring` we have this:

```
ls -r | % { $_.FullName.substring($pwd.Path.length+1) + $(if($_.PsIsContainer){'\'}) }
```

Answer (score 3):

> PowerShell Command For Directory List into Txt File:

For Full Path Directory List (Folder & File) to text file:

```
ls -r | % { $_.FullName + $(if($_.PsIsContainer){'\'}) } > filelist.txt
```

For Relative Path Directory List (Folder & File) to text file:

```
ls -r | % { $_.FullName.substring($pwd.Path.length+1) + $(if($_.PsIsContainer){'\'}) } > filelist.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Not powershell, but you can use the following within command prompt to recursively list files into a textfile:

```
dir *.* /s /b /a:-d > filelist.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this through the get-childitem command in PowerShell. Refer to the below syntax:

**Get-ChildItem "*Folder name or Path*" -Recurse | select FullName > list.txt**

This will help you write all the plain files and folders names recursively onto a file called list.txt
Refer to this for more information. https://ss64.com/ps/get-childitem.html

Answering late, but it might help someone!

Answer (score 0):

```
(ls $path -r).FullName | % {if((get-item "$_").psiscontainer){"$_\"}else{$_}}
```

Only use in PS 3.0

Answer (score 0):

I made an improved version of the code submitted (since the code output are inside powershell which has an output limit)

1. Shift + Right Click in the folder you're trying to scan files and folder on
2. copy and paste this (just edit your_pc_name)

dir -r  | % { if ($*.PsIsContainer) { $*.FullName + "" } else { $_.FullName } }  | Out-File -FilePath c:\users\your_pc_name\desktop\OUTPUT.txt

This will print all the files and folders into a txt file in your dekstop.

extra tips:

1. copy the output and paste it in excel
2. use ctrl + f to search for the filename you wanted.

This help me a lot in searching for a large database of files.